# check weather app is live on market or not?

Tags: java, android

i am developing an app in which i have get all installed app from from my phone and i have display it in listview and want to share it. and there are automatically make market link with formulla "market url + package name".it all going to fine. but here i need to check weather this (xyz)app is live in market or not?

i have tried to find out , but can get more information regarding it so please help me out from this

Thanks
Nik

Comment: What according to your definition is _live_, you mean currently installable? Don't think there is any api for this. You might just have to have a service somewhere that scraps/infers this data.

Comment: i mean to say... on android market.....

Answer (score 1):

There is no official API for this, so, in general, no. Just add your links, worst that could happen is that you get a 'no matching app found' or similar error. If you are trying to do this dynamically, it can't be done without using some unofficial API or scraping, which could be against Google Play terms of use.

Comment: is there any cracking idea ,,, that do this functionality same to same

Comment: not sure what you mean by cracking idea, Nikolay's answer makes a lot of sense though.